# Why is curl links redirecting through localhost?

Tags: php, google-chrome, curl

Right now, I have the current php code:

```
<?php 

include('simple_html_dom.php');

# set up the request parameters
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/search?q=sport+news');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
?>
```

when this code is run, it returns a google page with the search results corresponding to the search sport news. Although, when you try to click on any one of theese links, it redirects you to 'localhost:/--url--'. How do I prevent curl from redirecting to localhost and rather redirect to the actual site?

I am currently using wampserver for testing.

Comment: Its likely respecting the url it came from, which was your local host. Isnt this what you want? Of course this is what you want. Its not uncommon to do "testing" from localhost. When you want it to redirect to the "real" site, thats when you go live by uploading to the real site.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this from happening on localhost and make this work normally?

Comment: Is there any reason for a person to visit your local host? Check your api creds you applied for. Likely they list local host. My local host is different from yours and everyone else's. Only your computer / dev env knows local host as your machine .......... (unless of course you are a static ip? At which point your downloads folder *does* look interesting. Who are these ppl in your pictures folder? )

Comment: hi Sid, would you consider pasting a part of $result with a URL? just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Google's result page is using relative URLs in the links.

```
<a href="/url?q=https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/43634915&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjX (...)
```

Notice that the href starts with: `/` not with a domain such as `href="https://foobar.com/url?q=`.

Therefore, the links will use the hostname of the page serving the results.

Te reason you get `localhost` in the results when clicking them, is that you are serving this code from localhost.

One solution could be to use the [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) PHP extension to parse links, and add a hostname, so that the result links are absolute, rather than relative.

For example:

```
// Ignore HTML errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// Instantiate parser
$dom = new DOMDocument;

// Load HTML into DOM document parser
$dom->loadXML($result);

// Select anchor tags
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

// Iterate through all links
foreach ($links as $link) {

    // Get relative link value
    $relativePath = $link->getAttribute('href');

    // Check if this is a relative link
    if (substr($relativePath, 0, 1) === '/') {
        
        // Prepend Google domain
        $link->setAttribute('href', "https://google.com/" . $relativePath);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but every time I run this code, I get an error with the loadXML($result) line that says:

Comment: DOMDocument::loadXML(): StartTag: invalid element name in Entity

Comment: and it says: Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Extra content at the end of the document in Entity

Comment: @SidNutthi, its because of HTML errors, you can solve this by adding this line to the top before all the other code:  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and I can't even tell you how happy I am. You have truly been a great help to me, thank you @Cyril Graze.